Double spaced sections, single spaced subsections in table of contents
The thesis requirements are that, in the table of contents, the sections should be double spaced and the subsections single spaced. I'm having a really hard time getting this set up. Here is the feedback I've gotten and am trying to fullfill:

The code that I believe is relevant is:
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{setspace} \doublespacing{}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

% table of contents modification
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\titlecontents{section}[24pt]{\addvspace{0.5em}}{\thecontentslabel{} \hspace{0.5em}}{}{\dotfill \hspace{0.5em} \thecontentspage}[\addvspace{0.5em}]
\titlecontents{subsection}[48pt]{}{\thecontentslabel{} \hspace{0.5em}}{}{\dotfill \hspace{0.5em} \thecontentspage}[]
% rename
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\normalsize\normalfont{}TABLE OF CONTENTS\vspace{2mm}}
% work with tocloft to remove page number
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}}

\begin{document}
   % table of contents
    \begin{centering}
        \begin{singlespace}
            \tableofcontents{}
        \end{singlespace}
    \end{centering}
    \newpage

   \section{first}
   \section{second}
   \section{third}
      \subsection{third.a}
      \subsection{third.b}
      \subsection{third.c}
   \section{fourth}
\end{document}

The strategy I've tried in this code is to put the table of contents into singlespace enviornment and add vspace{0.5em} for sections to imitate a double space. This seems to work except for when there's subsections as shown in the image. I've tried several other variations like putting section into double space enviornment and subsection into single space enviornment and other hard coded spacing techniques. (I think my editor is taking calipers to this, cause some of these measurements I'm being given in the feedback are within a hundredth of an inch).

Welcome to TeX.SE. Your code doesn't compile as \headershift isn't defined. Please fix.

Incidentally, since you're using the tocloft package, why do you run \renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}} instead of just \tocloftpagestyle{empty}? And, what's with the {} appendages in \doublespacing{}, \thecontentslabel{}, \normalfont{}, and \tableofcontents{}? And, the name of the environment is center, not centering.

\headershift isn't relevant and is removed and it now compiles. Thanks.
For the page style, I don't remember. Your suggestion seems to produce the same results, I probably pulled it from some other exchange post.

If you were to use report or book class, you automatically get "double spacing" before chapters and "single spacing" before sections.  No setspace needed.

@Mico The center environment adds unwanted vspace. I've gotten in the habit of using {} because my lenter yells at me if I don't and from what I remember some commands can do unwanted behavior without it.

@JohnKormylo I could change the class, but that changes a lot more than just the spacing and I would prefer a local solution.

It should be mentioned that \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}} will add a 10pt gap between toc entires.  It can also be used on lof and lot.

This is a solution, but is not satisfying. The strategy is to add a double-space before each section, and then for a specific section, add some vspace below it in the table of contents as so:
\section{first}
   \section{second}
   \section{third}
   \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}}
      \subsection{third.a}
      \subsection{third.b}
      \subsection{third.c}
   \section{fourth}

This is not satisfying as I feel like there should be a way to do this for all sections/subsections without having to go through and edit specific ones and thus splitting the editing of the table of contents through the whole document.

What does adding this to your preamble do to your ToC: \AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{1em}}}

@Werner seems to do the same thing as \vspace{1em} in the before-code section of the \titlecontents command, adds some vspace before each section in the toc.

True. Allows you to insert a command in the ToC with every \section, and can be extended for \subsection.

Something like this? I've tried to assign all ToC-related settings to the tocloft package. Framelines around the text block are shown because the showframe package is loaded.

\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % omit in real document
\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing
\usepackage{indentfirst}

%% Not sure if this is needed:
\usepackage{secdot} % place dots after section numbers in section-level headers
\sectiondot{subsection} % ditto for subsection headers

%% Table of contents settings
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase{Table of Contents}}
\tocloftpagestyle{empty}
%%% If only first page of ToC should be without page number: 
%%% \renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{24pt}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{48pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{1\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\hspace*{24pt}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\hspace*{24pt}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{1em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setstretch{1}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\newpage

\section[FIRST]{First} % Uppercase section-level entries in ToC
\section[SECOND]{Second}
\section[THIRD]{Third}
\subsection{Third.a}
\subsection{Third.b}
\subsection{Third.c}
\section[FOURTH]{Fourth}

\end{document}


It's close, but there needs to be a double space between the third section and its subsections as well.
